# C++ static library: implement definitions in wrappers/bridges toward native mobile methods (Java, Objective-C)

Tags: c++, cross-platform, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a C++ static library (`.a`) that I'd like to use in native mobile development.

To do so, I have to create bridges between C++ and the native languages/SDKs :

- `java` (Android) : `JNI`
- `C#` (Windows) : `P\Invoke`
- `Objective-C` (iOS) : `Objective-C++` modules

Now, let's say that the code implemented in my C++ static library is heavily dependent on this one function :

`const void sendRawData(std::vector<unsigned char> data);`

Here's the thing: this method is not implemented in my library, just defined. For all three targets mentioned earlier, there is a similar method: for example, `void sendData(String data);` in `java`.

Is it possible to compile - for example - an Android library (`.aar` file), where the `sendRawData` symbol from the static library's method is implemented in a part of my `android-studio` project, where it's bridged to the previously mentioned native similar method?

Regarding iOS, we could generate a `.framework` library using `xcode`, with a similar method.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "this method is not implemented in my library, just defined." A function is defined in a C++ library if and only if it is implemented in
that library. "Defined" is synonymous with "implemented". What do you mean?

Comment: @MikeKinghan it is declared, but not defined. My mistake.

Comment: You mean that it is listed in the symbol table of the library as an undefined function that you can see with some suitable tool? Can you add that evidence to 
your post please?

Comment: I added some code regarding the generation of such a static library, and more details about what I want to do with it, I think my original post wasn't clear enough

Comment: I just found out about weak symbols (`__attribute__((weak))`) and I think that's the exact thing I was looking for... I'll do a complete write-up of the solution I've thought in the next few days, thanks for your questions @MikeKinghan, you rubber-ducked me real good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This answer is a work in progress.

So you want to take a C++ static library and bridge one of its functions (undefined at the library's compilation) to a native mobile function (iOS/Android/Windows Phone).

---

First, the most important question:

### Why would you ever want to do that?

**In my case,** it was a mix of code maintenance (having three teams work on three different code-bases just to add a small feature is annoying), and lowering the project's costs. Let's say that you're working on some highly sensitive code, chances are you'll have to certificate the whole code handling the logic. Three targets means three times more certifications. So, it was very important to develop the whole logic of the program inside a C++ library that would be used **exactly** as is by other platforms (iOS, Android, Windows Phone), which means exact same CRC32.

---

### How are we going to do that?

We're going to do a complete walk-through of how to do this, on each platform. In the example, we'll declare a C++ `static void NativePrint(std::string str)` method, which will be called by a C++ module called `NativeAPI`. This API is later to be exposed to mobile developer (which we will do, using [Djinni](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni)) to actually allow them to call your generic C++ method.

This can be split into 6 steps:

### 1. Compile the static library

**CallsNativePrint.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
class CallsNativePrint
{
public:
    static void __attribute__((weak)) NativePrint(int32_t i);
};
```

**NativeAPI.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "CallsNativePrint.h"
class NativeAPI
{
public:
    static void IncrementAndCallNativePrint(int32_t i);
};
```

**NativeAPI.cpp:**

```
#include "NativeAPI.h"
void NativeAPI::IncrementAndCallNativePrint(int32_t i)
{
    // You can here do whatever you want with str.
    // The purpose of this exercise is to define a logic inside
    // of your C++ code, not just to call native methods.
    i++;
    CallsNativePrint::NativePrint(i);
}
```

**Compilation: Makefile**

```
.PHONY:all
all:
    gcc -std=c++11 -c NativeAPI.cpp -o NativeAPI.o
    ar rcs libNativePrint.a NativeAPI.o
```

After this step, you have your native library properly compiled. The most important part of this is in *CallsNativePrint.h*: `static void __attribute__((weak)) NativePrint(std::string str);`

The `__attribute__((weak))` part tells the compiler that this function's symbol is to be linked *weakly*, which means that we'll later be able to override this symbol with a strong one (all symbols are strong by default).

Once this step is over, we can check the compiled library and check that our function's symbol is, indeed, weakly-typed:

```
$ nm libNativePrint.a

NativeAPI.o:
   SUCCESS -->   w _ZN16CallsNativePrint11NativePrintEi
0000000000000000 T _ZN9NativeAPI27IncrementAndCallNativePrintEi
0000000000000000 r _ZStL19piecewise_construct
```

For the next steps, we'll split it between Android and iOS, starting with Android.

## Android

### 2. Create the Android Studio project

To limit our work, we'll let Android Studio generate the whole back-bone of the project. We'll then use its builder tools to incorporate our C++ static library into the solution.

Go ahead and create a new Android Studio project:

- Name: `MyNativeAndroidLibrary`
- Company domain: `overflow.stack.com`
- Include C++ support: checked.
- Select the form factors your app will run on: I checked the "Phone and Tablet" case with "API 15: Android 4.0.3" although I doubt it has much importance.
- Do not add any activity.
- I chose the C++11 toolchain without exceptions or runtime type information support.

Firstly, we'll compile our previously-created source code using `cmake`, inside of `android-studio`. This will make things easier because `android-studio` will automatically generate every needed architecture and put them in the correct folders.

Having your project inspector in `Android` mode, head toward `ExternalBuildFiles/CMakeLists.txt`, erase everything in it, and add this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Path to our source code
set(LIB_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../native-library-cpp)

# Add our c++ static library (android-studio recompiles it)
add_library(native-library-cpp STATIC ${LIB_SRC_DIR}/NativeAPI.cpp)
include_directories(${LIB_SRC_DIR}/)

# Native shared library generated by android-studio: will contain JNI code
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
include_directories(src/main/cpp/)

# Find native Android logging library: that's what we'll call!
find_library(log-lib log)
# Link the JNI shared library with our static library
target_link_libraries(native-lib
                      native-library-cpp log-lib)
```

Make sure to change the `LIB_SRC_DIR` path to whatever matches yours. My Android Studio project directory and the directory containing the native C++ lib are in the same directory.

Then, we want to configure Android Studio to generate an `.aar` file. Go to `app:build.gradle`, and change the first line (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`) to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`. You also have to remove the line `applicationId`, else the build will fail.

Once that's done, we can start working on bridging the C++ method to our native Java method!

### 3. Bridge the C++ `NativePrint` method to a native Android function

To do so, we'll code in the `native-lib.cpp` file automatically generated by Android Studio. First of all, create a `native-lib.h` file (by right-clicking on `native-lib.cpp`) containing the following:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <string>

#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>

// JNI fields used to link C++ to Java
extern JavaVM   *jvm;
extern JNIEnv   *env;
extern jclass    cls;
extern jmethodID mid;

class CallsNativePrint
{
private:
    // JNI initializers
    static bool _hasBeenInitialized;
    static void InitializeJNIFields();
    static bool GetNativeMethod();

public:
    static void NativePrint(int32_t i); // We're going to re-define this symbol
    // Note that it is already existing in native-library-cpp, as a weak symbol.
};
```

This header defines a few things:

- It includes whatever's used in it.
- It declares some extern JNI-related variables: this is actually recommended as JNI best practices. Getting references to java classes or methods takes a long time. You don't want to do that every time you call a
  JNI method. Same for getting a reference to the JVM/Java env.
- It declares the CallsNativePrint class. In there, we re-declare the `static void NativePrint(int32_t i)` method. Once defined, its symbol will erase the one in the static library, and it's the method that will be called whenever `IncrementAndCallNativePrint` is called!

Now, in `native-lib.cpp`, we have to dump all this documented code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include "native-lib.h"

// JNI-related variables declaration
JavaVM   *jvm;
JNIEnv   *env;
jclass    cls;
jmethodID mid;

bool CallsNativePrint::_hasBeenInitialized = false;

void CallsNativePrint::InitializeJNIFields()
{
    env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.name = NULL;
    args.group = NULL;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, &args);
    CallsNativePrint::_hasBeenInitialized = true;
}

// Find a Java method based on class name ("JavaBridge"),
// method name ("PrintInteger"), and JNI prototype string ("(I)V").
bool CallsNativePrint::GetNativeMethod()
{
    if (cls || mid)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "native-lib",
                            "Native method has already been recovered!");
        return true;
    }

    cls = env->FindClass("JavaBridge");
    if (!cls) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "native-lib",
                            "Couldn't find Java JavaBridge class!");
        return false;
    }

    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "PrintInteger",
                                           "(I)V");
    if (mid == nullptr)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "native-lib",
                            "Couldn't find Java StaticRuaBridge::SendRawCommandBridge method!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Converts int32_t to jint (no conversion needed in this case!)
// then calls the `mid` method recovered in GetNativeMethod().
void CallsNativePrint::NativePrint(int32_t i)
{
    if (!_hasBeenInitialized) { InitializeJNIFields(); }

    if (GetNativeMethod())
    {
        jint ji = i;
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, ji); // Call the JavaBridge method!
    }
}
```

Once that's done, we have to actually write the Java code we're calling from the JNI. Create a `JavaBridge.java` java class (right click on the `java/` folder), and put that in it:

```
package com.stack.overflow.mynativeandroidlibrary;

import android.util.Log;

public class JavaBridge {
    public static void PrintInteger(int i) {
        Log.i("JavaBridge", "PrintInteger: " + i);
    }
}
```

If this has been properly done, once everything is linked together, `CallsNativePrint::NativePrint(int32_t i)` should now be associated to the code at the end of `native-lib.cpp`, which means JNI code directly calling a Java method. Success!

Now, if we want our library to be of any use, we need to expose a Java API that will allow Android developers to directly call methods defined in our C++ library ; in our case, it will be a direct call from Java to `IncrementAndCallNativePrint(int32_t i)`!

To check that everything is working fine, you can already generate an `.aar` file by clicking on the top bar on `Build -> Build APK`.

### 4. Expose the C++ methods to Android developers

For this part, we'll extensively use [Djinni.](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni) First, install it.

Then, create a `djinni-generation/` folder at the root of your project. Inside this project, create an `api.djinni` file with this content:

```
NativeAPIExposer = interface +c {
    static IncrementAndCallNativePrint(i: i32);
}
```

Using `djinni`, this will allow us to create C++, Objective-C, and Java files describing this API (which will be implemented in `C`, note the `+c`!).

Create another file named `run-djinni.sh`, with this content:

```
#! /usr/bin/env /bin/bash

base_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cpp_out="$base_dir/generated-src/cpp"
jni_out="$base_dir/generated-src/jni"
java_out="$base_dir/generated-src/java/com/stack/overflow"
objc_out="$base_dir/generated-src/objc"

java_package="com.stack.overflow"
namespace="native_api"
djinni="$base_dir/api.djinni"

mkdir ./generated-src/
djinni                                \
   --java-out $java_out               \
   --java-package $java_package       \
   --ident-java-field mFooBar         \
                                      \
   --cpp-out $cpp_out                 \
   --cpp-namespace $namespace         \
                                      \
   --jni-out $jni_out                 \
   --ident-jni-class NativeFooBar     \
   --ident-jni-file NativeFooBar      \
                                      \
   --objc-out $objc_out               \
   --objc-type-prefix DB              \
                                      \
   --idl $djinni
```

Once this done, the `generated-src/` folder will be populated like so:

```
$ tree -pf ./generated-src/
generated-src
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/cpp
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  generated-src/cpp/NativeAPIExposer.hpp
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/java
│   └── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/java/com
│       └── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/java/com/stack
│           └── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/java/com/stack/overflow
│               └── [-rw-rw-r--]  generated-src/java/com/stack/overflow/NativeAPIExposer.java
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/jni
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  generated-src/jni/NativeNativeAPIExposer.cpp
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  generated-src/jni/NativeNativeAPIExposer.hpp
└── [drwxrwxr-x]  generated-src/objc
    └── [-rw-rw-r--]  generated-src/objc/DBNativeAPIExposer.h
```

For the Android project, grab the files in `generated-src/cpp/`, `generated-src/java/`, and `generated-src/jni/`, and import them into the respective folders in Android Studio.

**Note:** If you can't find the `jni/` folder, switch from `Android` project view to `Project` project view.

We now have to implement the `NativeAPIExposer` method. Create a `NativeAPIExposer.cpp` file in the `cpp/` folder, with this content:

```
#include "NativeAPIExposer.hpp"
#include "NativeAPI.h"

void native_api::NativeAPIExposer::IncrementAndCallNativePrint(int32_t i)
{
    NativeAPI::IncrementAndCallNativePrint(i); // Call the native method!
}
```

We now have to compile the new lib and add them to the CMakeLists.txt file :

```
# Native API exposer
set(DJINNI_PATH RELATIVE/PATH/TO/DJINNI)
add_library(native-api-lib SHARED
            src/main/cpp/NativeAPIExposer.cpp
            src/main/jni/NativeNativeAPIExposer.cpp
            ${DJINNI_PATH}/support-lib/jni/djinni_main.cpp
            ${DJINNI_PATH}/support-lib/jni/djinni_support.cpp)
include_directories(src/main/cpp/ src/main/jni/ ${DJINNI_PATH}/support-lib/jni/)
```

Edit the following line:

```
target_link_libraries(native-lib native-library-cpp log-lib)
```

To:

```
target_link_libraries(native-lib native-library-cpp log-lib native-api-lib)
```

### 5. Generate the `.aar` library

As mentioned earlier, at this point all you have to do is click on the top bar on `Build -> Build APK`.

### 6. Use the native library in another Android project

Start by creating a new Android Studio project (with an empty activity), then add the generated `.aar` as a dependency.

To do so:

- `File -> New -> New Module`, « Import .JAR/.AAR Package », and select the one generated by Android Studio, which should be in "MyNativeAndroidLibrary/app/build/outputs/aar/".
- Right click on your project -> Open Module Settings -> Dependencies -> Add module dependency -> Add our very own module.

Inside the code of the activity, you should be able to access our function using the following code:

## iOS

### 2. Create the Android Studio project

Placeholder

### 3. Bridge the C++ `NativePrint` method to a native iOS function

Placeholder

### 4. Export the C++ methods to iOS developers

For this part, we'll extensively use [Djinni.](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni)

### 5. Generate the `.framework` library

Placeholder

### 6. Use the native library in another iOS project